# Azure DNS CNAME subdomain

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, cname

We have two sites:

- proddomain.com (proddomain.azurewebsites.net)
- stagingdomain.azurewebsites.net

We need to make stagingdomain.azurewebsites.net a subdomain of proddomain.com, for example stagingdomain.proddomain.com. We added a CNAME of "stagingdomain" to proddomain.com DNS, but when going to the url stagingdomain.proddomain.com, it just gives a 404 blue screen.

When i do DNS check, both stagingdomain.proddomain.com and stagingdomain.azurewebsites.net point to the same IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map a subdomain to web sites in your Azure app service, you could add a `CNAME` record for your `subdomain` of `proddomain.com`. Then add such subdomain `hostname` in your Azure app service. You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain) to Map your domain.

Probably, in this case, there is missing a `hostname` like `stagingdomain.proddomain.com` in the **custom domains** of app service `stagingdomain.azurewebsites.net`.

From this picture, you could follow these steps: app services or web app---custom domains---add hostname---validate---add hostname.
[image]

Then, you could verify these DNS records from [digwebinterface](https://digwebinterface.com/). You could also run `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear cache in the command prompt and test DNS resolution again.